# Is it possible to convert elements of an array to local variables in JavaScript, setting the variable name to the element's key?

Tags: javascript

Here is an example to illustrate the desired behaviour:

```
processNames : function () {
    var names = getNames();

    // This is desired:
    processName(one);

    // Whereas this is required:
    processName(names.one);
},
processName: function (name) {
    // TODO
    return name;
},
getNames : function () {
    return [
        one = "Bob", 
        two = "Alan", 
        three = "Ben" 
    ];
}
```

The desired output is a variable in local scope, one for each element of the `names` array, where the variable's name is its key within the array and its value is its corresponding value.

Comment: Quite honestly, no, variable variables are a terrible idea and should not be used even if it were possible.

Comment: Also, `[one = 'Bob', ...]` is either invalid syntax or nonsense, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Sounds more like you want an object.